# Indexing a column in all content types that use it

Tags: list, content-type, list-view-threshold, indexed-column

I'm wondering if it's possible to add an Index to a column in every Item of a specific Content Type.

I'm still having issues with the List View Threshold in an Intranet Site Collection so that CQWP's are failing to return items for users.

I thought I might be able to apply the indexing once rather than for every List that uses the Content Type in question `Event`

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes are associated with List. So you need to modify the list and add index.

You can automate this using PowerShell.

```
$site = Get-SPsite http://siteurl 

foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)  
{ 
    #foreach ($list in $web.Lists) 
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $web.Lists.Count; $i++)
    {
        $list = $web.Lists[$i]
        foreach ($ct in $list.ContentTypes)  
        {  
            if ($ct.Name -eq "Your Content Type Name")  
            {  
                #Logic to create index 
                $field = $list.Fields["Field Name To Index"]
                $field.Indexed = $true
                $field.Update()
            } 
        } 
    }  
    $web.Dispose()  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Amal.
I'll test it and post back once I'm done.

Comment: It looks like I've failed to use your script.
Initially I get an error, after the script appeared to be running, that states...
"foreach : An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.."
I Googled this and found some suggestion that using a for loop rather than foreach would prevent the items collected earlier from being changed.
I've not managed to make that work yet.

Comment: Ok in that case replace foreach with a for loop.. `for($i=0;$i -lt $web.lists.Count; $i++)`.. Then use `$list = $web.Lists[$i]`.. Check updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again Amal. That worked a treat.
I'd already grabbed the for loop example but was failing to insert it in the correct place.